# Does doctrine support multiple orderBy?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine 2.0, and want to sort on 2 properties:

```
$qb->addOrderBy('o.prop1', 'ASC')->addOrderBy('o.prop2', 'ASC')
```

Only sorts on prop2.

This won't work (only in Doctrine 1)

```
$qb->addOrderBy('o.prop1 ASC', 'o.prop2 ASC')
```

How can I sort on 2 properties in DQL with Doctrine 2.0?

Comment: What you do seems right. Can you provide more code of what you do ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure. Try:

```
$qb->orderBy('o.prop1', 'ASC')->addOrderBy('o.prop2', 'ASC')
```

This works for me.